# Android: SeekBar onProgressChanged-event doesn't get fired when setting progress programmatically

Tags: android, seekbar

My onProgressChanged()-event doesn't get fired when I set the progress of a SeekBar programmatically, but it does get fired perfectly fine when I physically move the SeekBar slider.

I'd expect the event to fire when using setProgress() - the Android Developer Reference even states that:

> public abstract void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
>
> *Notification that the progress level has changed. Clients can use the fromUser parameter to distinguish user-initiated changes from those that occurred programmatically.*

Some code snippets from my project:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);               

    final SeekBar mySeekBar = ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar));
    
    mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // Do some stuff
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final SeekBar mySeekBar = ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar));
    mySeekBar.setProgress(someValue); // This SHOULD trigger onProgressChanged(), but it doesn't...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 for Romuald Brunet's answer:

Here was my "hack" to fix it:

```
        <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:progress="1"
            android:max="200" />
```

Note the progress="1", set the default progress in the layout to 1, then in my code when I actually default it to 0, a change in the progress occurs and the onProgressChanged() event fires.

Comment: didn't solved for me (holo everywhere + android 5.1.1)

Comment: this is not a fix nor hack because onProgressChanged won't get fired if the progress is set to 1

Answer (score 9):

Stumbled across the same problem just now.

In my case, the `onProgressChanged` did not get fired simply because the value **did not actually change**. I was setting the same value as the current one (`0` :)

(and I don't see anything wrong with your code)

Answer (score 3):

My listener didn't fire because I was calling `setProgress()` BEFORE setting the listener

Answer (score 1):

`SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged` is only called when the progress is actually changed, not necessarily when `setProgress` is called - this only happens if the new progress is different from the last.

Looking at [the source of SeekBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SeekBar.java), which extends [AbsSeekBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java) which in turn extends [ProgressBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java), we can see that a call to `setProgress()` doesn't fire the `onProgressChanged()` event unless the new progress is different from the previous one as seen in the source below.

```
/* 
    Snippet from ProgressBar.java 
*/

public void setProgress(int progress, boolean animate) {
    setProgressInternal(progress, false, animate);
}


synchronized boolean setProgressInternal(int progress, boolean fromUser, boolean animate) {
    if (mIndeterminate) {
        // Not applicable.
        return false;
    }

    progress = MathUtils.constrain(progress, mMin, mMax);
    if (progress == mProgress) {
        // No change from current.
        return false;
    }

    mProgress = progress;
    refreshProgress(R.id.progress, mProgress, fromUser, animate);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set progress=10 in xml file as shown below:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:progress="10"
  android:max="100" />
```

Then in main file write below code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            seekbar.setProgress(50)
                        }
                    }, 100);
```

Give delay less so that it doesn't affect the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the value has definitely changed, otherwise it won't be picked up. Put in 2 lines. The 1st not wanted. The 2nd desired.

```
seekbar.setProgress(7); // Necessary to force the change to desired
seekbar.setProgress(50); // Desired progress
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible workaround is to create own widget extending Seekbar and implementing two methods for your needs:

```
    private OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener;

    @Override
    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener l) {
        super.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(l);
        onSeekBarChangeListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        if (onSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            onSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because it stopped getting fired when the progress is set to 1 programmatically (which is the same bug).

What I did instead was to invoke the onProgressChanged() myself. I the seek bar is a member variable.

```
void setProgressValue(int progress){
    if(progress == 0){ //the default progress is 0. if i set it to 0 again the call back wont be invoked
        mSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
        onProgressChanged(progress,mSeekBar,false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    //things to be done when the call back is received
}
```

Posting in the hope of helping someone later.

Answer (score -1):

**I can confirm with certainty that `setProgress` works on Android version 6.0.1.**

Another [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28433145/975724)  said it was a bug.  If this was true, it is definitely no longer the case.

This code works on my test setup:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
    seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
}
```

As expected, the `SeekBar`'s `OnSeekBarChangeListener` is getting called.

For troubleshooting, make sure that you set the listener properly using `setOnSeekBarChangeListener()` and make sure you implement the interface functions.
Other SO answers seem to indicate that you should only call `setProgress()` from the UI thread.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18866598/975724) shows how that can be done.

Comment: @Downvoter. (or anyone else). I would like to know if there is an error in this answer so that it can be corrected. Thanks!

Comment: if (progress == mProgress) {
            // No change from current.
            return false;
        } 

this code is from ProgressBar.java you can check it yourself. If the progress is same as earlier it won't give you a callback

Answer (score -1):

simply call

```
 mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
       int i=    arg0.getProgress();
     //youre seekbar.setProgress(i);
    }
}
```